# Write Error during flashing stock ROM through SP Flash Tool

Tags: rom-flashing, custom-roms, stock-android, android-versions, stock-rom

I am trying to install the stock ROM of my xolo a500s ips by using the Smart Phone Flash Tool. i downloaded the stock ROM of my device from this link http://androidxda.com/download-xolo-stock-rom-model. The SP Flash tool and USB drivers were also included in the zip package.

When I try to flash the ROM, the progress is stopped at 70% and then this error is displayed on the screen: BROM ERROR : S-DA_SDMMC_WRITE_FAILED (3149).

Anyone knows how to fix this issue?